# can i disable channel event logging records in database for specific context ?

Tags: asterisk

i'm using the **cel ( channel event logging )** for billing because CDR is not accurate for many purposes.

everything works well.
but i want to know if **i can disable cel records for some contexts in my diaplan** . (like the **NoCDR()** function for cdr module).

i only need cel records for specific contexts in my diaplan.

**is there a function like NoCDR() or a setting to only allow cel records for specific contexts.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't

But you can delete it from database using external script or trigger.